# I can find the expressions but I don't want to replace everything of it (regex in vim)

Tags: regex, vim

I tried for some time now but I can't figure it out: I have text that looks like that:

```
xxx "fy1":
    xxx.xxx = fy;
    xxx;
xxx "tm1":
    xxx.xxx = tm;
    xxx;
...
```

And I want it to look like that:

```
xxx "fy1":
    xxx.xxx = fy1;
    xxx;
...
```

My problem is that I can find all occurences, where I want to put a "1" with

```
s/[ft][ymdhi];/???/g
```

but everything I put at the place of the question marks replaces the letters  too. The only thing I want to do is put a number after those two letters.

I thought about something with

```
\w{2}
```

in the search string too, but that finds everything with two letters before a semicolon, so I think I need the

```
[ft][ymdhi]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `\(...\)` along with `\1`:

```
:%s/\([ft][ymdhi]\);/\11;/
```

The escaped paranthes `\(...\)` sort of *store* what was matched between the paranthesis. The stored text can later be used again with `\1`.

In your case the `\11` has nothing to to with eleven, it's just a coincidence that the text you remembered with the paranthesis is followed by a `1`.

Answer (score 3):

You can make capture-groups so that in replacement reference the matched text. Or you can use vim's `\zs` to leave some matched text untouched, for example
this line does the job:

```
%s/[ft][ymdhi]\zs;/1;/g
```

`:h \zs and :h \ze` for details

If add `\ze` to this example too, it would be:

```
%s/[ft][ymdhi]\zs\ze;/1/g
```

It works too.